# On what basis does Stack Exchange bring out the "related questions"?

Tags: discussion, related-questions

On what basis does Stack Exchange bring out the "related questions" (while posting questions)? Most of the time they seem to be off-target with little or no semantic value to the question being asked. How can Stack Exchange improve upon this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IRIC, it uses SQL Server's built-in full-text search with the words from your question title (minus some stop words) as the query.

Answer (score 2):

> How can stackoverflow improve upon this?

It can convince users to properly tag their questions and write titles that actually *ask* the question rather than making some vague allusion to part of the technology involved.