# "Questions that may already have your answer" vs. "Related questions"

Tags: support, related-questions, duplicate-suggestions

Lately, my overall impression has been that the list of "Related questions" one sees once a question is posted is usually more relevant that the "Questions that may already have your answer" one is exposed to while typing.

My questions are :

- How are the two lists constructed?
- Are the two lists generated in any significantly different way or am I completely wrong in believing that there is a difference between the two?
- If there is a difference in the way the lists are constructed, how is the difference justified?

Comment: @random : 
 
I see how the question marked as duplicate answers the first part of the first bullet point, but it is not clear to me how it answers the rest of the question. Am I missing something? I am not reading answers to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected correctly?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234770/already-have-your-answer-search-results-better-than http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/search-box-vs-question-title http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254048/related-posts-not-related-what-does-the-algorithm http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/on-what-basis-does-stack-exchange-bring-out-the-related-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39720/search-algorithm-differences